# Creating a simple store but set function undefined

Tags: svelte

I'm trying to create a simple User store and put a couple of classic functions into it but I may have missed something...

Many thanks.

```html
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

// a simple user just for testing
const userTest = {
    uid: '89sdf2fdq2mP',
    email: 'john.galvin@yopmail.org',
    firstname: 'John',
    lastname: 'Galvin',
    phoneNumber: '',
    photoURL: '',
    emailVerified: false,
    sex: 0,
    date_of_birth: new Date(1990, 8, 1)
};

const user = writable(null);

// the user store
const userStore = {
    subscribe: user.subscribe,
    setUser: (user) => {
        userStore.set(user); // TypeError: userStore.set is not a function
    },
    saveUserProperty: (prop, value) => (userStore.prop = value), // to be tested later
    delete: () => {
        userStore.set(null);
    }
};

console.log(user); // an object containing set, subscribe and update method
userStore.setUser(userTest); // Error

export default userStore;
```

Comment: Did you already have a look at the [custom store](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/custom-stores) syntax in the tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `set` method is provided by the `user` store, not `userStore`. Also, use another variable to describe user data, since `user` is the name of your initial store. Finally, see below for a proper implementation of `saveUserProperty`.

```js
// the user store
const userStore = {
    subscribe: user.subscribe,
    setUser: (u) => {
        user.set(u); // TypeError: userStore.set is not a function
    },
    // saveUserProperty: (prop, value) => (userStore[prop] = value), // to be tested later
    delete: () => {
        user.set(null);
    }
};
```

If I understand what your aim is, the `saveUserProperty` method would be:

```js
    saveUserProperty: (prop, value) => {
        user.update((u) => ({ ...u, [prop]: value }))
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much Thomas! Have a great New Year's Eve :)